# Bash Parse file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that I want to parse using sed, but after many attemps, I didn't succeed.
This is the source file :

```
. . exported "SCHEMA1"."IJK_ECX_LEDGER_HST_2009"            806.6 KB   25391 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA1"."IJK_ECX_JGEN_ACCT_ENTRY_HST_2009"   1.000 MB   25591 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA2"."IJK_ECX_JRNL_LN_HST_2009"           1.156 MB   25596 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA2"."IJK_ECX_OPEN_ITEM_GL_HST_2009"      663.4 KB   15062 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA1"."IJK_ECX_XLATITEM_HST_2009"          932.9 KB   42277 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA1"."IJK_ECX_JRNL_HEADER_HST_2009"       9.585 KB       4 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA5"."IJK_ECX_CA_JGEN_CHQ_HST_2009"           0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA1"."IJK_ECX_CA_JRNL_LN_HST_2009"            0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA5"."IJK_ECX_DISTRIB_LINE_HST_2009"          0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA1"."IJK_ECX_GP_ACC_LINE_HST_2009"           0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA5"."IJK_ECX_IN018_JRNL_H_HST_2009"          0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA1"."IJK_ECX_IN094_A_SUIV_HST_2009"          0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA5"."IJK_ECX_IN094_B_SUIV_HST_2009"          0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA5"."IJK_ECX_IN094_LN_AUD_HST_2009"          0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA0"."IJK_ECX_JGEN_ACT_HST_2009"              0 KB       0 rows
. . exported "SCHEMA1"."IJK_ECX_JGEN_CASH_HST_2009"             0 KB       0 rows
```

And this is what I want :

```
IJK_ECX_LEDGER_HST_2009,25391
IJK_ECX_JGEN_ACCT_ENTRY_HST_2009,25591
IJK_ECX_JRNL_LN_HST_2009,25596
IJK_ECX_OPEN_ITEM_GL_HST_2009,15062
IJK_ECX_XLATITEM_HST_2009,42277
IJK_ECX_CA_JGEN_CHQ_HST_2009, 0
IJK_ECX_CA_JRNL_LN_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_DISTRIB_LINE_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_GP_ACC_LINE_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_IN018_JRNL_H_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_IN094_A_SUIV_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_IN094_B_SUIV_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_IN094_LN_AUD_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_JGEN_ACT_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_JGEN_CASH_HST_2009,0
```

The number after the comma corresponds to the number of rows.
Do you have any idea how I could do this ?
Thanks for your help,

Steve

Comment: `but after many attemps, I didn't succeed` -- consider posting your attempts.

Comment: I found this works, but is there another way ? cat test.txt | grep ". . exported" | sed 's/. . exported "[A-Z]*"."//g' | sed 's/ rows//g' | sed 's/" [^"]* /,/g'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s\n", $4, $7}' file | awk -F\" '{printf "%s,%s\n", $4,$5}'
IJK_ECX_LEDGER_HST_2009,25391
IJK_ECX_JGEN_ACCT_ENTRY_HST_2009,25591
IJK_ECX_JRNL_LN_HST_2009,25596
IJK_ECX_OPEN_ITEM_GL_HST_2009,15062
IJK_ECX_XLATITEM_HST_2009,42277
IJK_ECX_JRNL_HEADER_HST_2009,4
IJK_ECX_CA_JGEN_CHQ_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_CA_JRNL_LN_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_DISTRIB_LINE_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_GP_ACC_LINE_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_IN018_JRNL_H_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_IN094_A_SUIV_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_IN094_B_SUIV_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_IN094_LN_AUD_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_JGEN_ACT_HST_2009,0
IJK_ECX_JGEN_CASH_HST_2009,0
```

**EDIT:** If you run it without the second part the output looks like this:

```
"SCHEMA1"."IJK_ECX_LEDGER_HST_2009"25391
```

To reach your desired output we have to split again with the second awk part. `-F\"` means split at `"` and print only values 4 and 5, comma separated.

Comment: Thanks you, this is exactly what I wanted! But I don't how this part (awk -F\" '{printf "%s,%s\n", $4,$5}') works, could you explain it to me please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^.*"."\([^"]*\)"[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{2\}\([0-9]\{1,\}[[:blank:]].*/\1,\3/' YourFile
```

on GNU sed add -posix